Question how can I create custom access token if I deployed supabase in self hosting docker?
I'm trying to create a Hook: Custom access token but I can't get it to work...
Supabase I deployed in self-hosting version.
The documentation says to add fields to config.toml I found it in supabase/supabase/config.toml . But as I understand it is not what I need. Question how can I create custom access token if I deployed supabase in self hosting docker ?
This is the documentation I used to create the Custom access token -
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-hooks#hook-custom-access-token
This is the documentation I used to deploy supabase -
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/self-hosting/docker

What is the custom access token used to access in this scenario that you are talking about? To access your database as an authenticated user? If so, you can just sign up using the auth method. https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signup
